# How to ungroup the grouped record based on count column using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below data set obtained after group by dept and loc.

dept id        loc    count

100               a      2

300               c    1

I need out put like below

deptid    loc

100        a

100        a

300        c

please help

Comment: Don't use group by then. Or share your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use `Recursive Queries` to get the desired result.

```
with cte(deptid, loc, cnt) as 
(select deptid, loc, cnt - 1 from dept
union all
select cte.deptid, cte.loc, cte.cnt - 1
from cte, dept
where dept.deptid = cte.deptid and dept.loc = cte.loc
and cte.cnt > 0)
select deptid, loc from cte order by deptid, loc;
```

**DB Fiddle Link:** https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0580680ecf0b47b4933e3a4731b62b4a

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate rows (inline view rws) according to the maximum value for count column, then join that to your base table like below :

```sql
select t.DEPT_ID, t.LOC
from your_table t
join (
    select level lvl from dual
    connect by level <= (select max(count) from your_table )
 )rws
     on rws.lvl <= t.count
order by 1, 2
;
```